# PHP - Can't get $_Server['REMOTE_ADDR'] to match the IP its providing in IF statement

Tags: php

I'm trying to whitelist two IP's for a specific script, I'm not using mod_rewrite because other scripts are public. I can't get this if statement to return false even though the ip address `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is one of the two in my expression

```
if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != "192.168.1.1" || $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != "192.168.1.2"){
    echo "Not allowed<br>";
    echo "remote_addr ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    header("HTTP/1.1 500");
    exit;
```

This is what I get when I hit the page

```
Not allowed
remote_addr 192.168.1.2
```

Comment: `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != "192.168.1.1" || $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != "192.168.1.2"` is an impossible condition. It will always be true.

Comment: Use `&&` operator. As, It will always be true.

Comment: change the `!=` to `==` for this to make sense in the way you intend.

Comment: yeah. The only way to make what you posted to work would be to use the `&&` operator. Or, remove the first one. *Problem solved* ;-) (Unless you're connect to both addresses at the same time, which is highly unlikely).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read up on boolean logic, particularly [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

```
not(P) OR not(Q)  => NOT(P AND Q)
```

Since your two ips are different, you're doing the following:

```
1. (IP1 != x) OR (IP1 != x)
2. not(IP1 = x) OR not(IP1 = x)
3. not((IP1 = x) AND (IP1 = x))
4. not(FALSE)
5. TRUE
```

Since the two ips are different, it is impossible for them to BOTH be equal to `x` at the same time.

Comment: thanks for helping clarify, when it comes to logic I often have a hard time wrapping my head around it.